# Transform Restsharp call to asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asynchronous, restsharp

I've this function :

```
public string GetSecurityCrumb()
    {
        string uri = $"{Url}/crumbIssuer/api/xml";// URL where the XML is available
        var client = new RestClient(uri); // define it as the actual client
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        byte[] ua = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Username + ":" + ApiToken); // Encoding username and token in base 64

        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(ua));// adding header to get the xml
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(response.Content);// parsing the content of the response in a document

        var crumb = document.Root.Element("crumb").Value;// retrieve the content of the crumb only

        return crumb;
    }
```

I tried a lot of things to do this aynchronous, but I just don't see how I can return string value if I change my Rest call to an aynschronous one.

Maybe somebody already got this kind of problem and could help me.

**EDIT 1**

I tried this :

```
public async Task<string> GetSecurityCrumb()
    {
        string uri = $"{Url}/crumbIssuer/api/xml";// URL where the XML is available
        var client = new RestClient(uri); // define it as the actual client
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        byte[] ua = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Username + ":" + ApiToken); // Encoding username and token in base 64

        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(ua));// adding header to get the xml
        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(response.Content);// parsing the content of the response in a document

        var crumb = document.Root.Element("crumb").Value;// retrieve the content of the crumb only

        return crumb;
    }
```

but it seems like I need to put await before all my calls on this method and use GetSecurityCrumb().Result to get the real content. I don't know if it's the best way because I've totally 0 error handlers at the moment. A lot of my methods depend of this one so I prefer having the best solution

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, possibly with a code sample

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like I need to put await before all my calls on this method and use GetSecurityCrumb().Result to get the real content

You shouldn't call `.Result` - that would block on the asynchronous method, removing all the benefits of asynchronous code in the first place.

It's normal to `await` the task returned from `GetSecurityCrumb()`. And using that `await` means that the calling method should also be marked `async` and return a task. Which means that *its* callers should use `await`, so *they* should be made `async`, etc. [This is all perfectly normal and is the correct way to use `async`/`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).